# tkinter image not showing in label on button press

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to write a simple program which inserts an image (from a website) into a label on a button press. Here's what I have so far

```
# Import the function for downloading web pages
from urllib import urlopen

# Import the regular expression function
from re import findall

# Import the Tkinter functions
from Tkinter import *    

# Import a constructor for converting byte data to character strings 
from StringIO import *
import io

# Import the Python Imaging Library module (comment this line out
# if you do not intend to use PIL in your solution)
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#create window
root = Tk()

def button():
  url = 'http://www.technologyreview.com/topnews.rss'
  html = urlopen(_url).read()
  img_url = findall('<<media:content url="(.+\.jpg)"',html)
  url = img_url[0] #First instance of image url ending in JPG.


  image_bytes = urlopen(url).read()
# internal data file
  data_stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
# open as a PIL image object
  pil_image = Image.open(data_stream)
#resize
  pil_image= pil_image.resize((400, 400),Image.ANTIALIAS)
# optionally show image info
# get the size of the image
  w, h = pil_image.size
# split off image file name
  fname = url.split('/')[-1]
  sf = "{} ({}x{})".format(fname, w, h)
  root.title(sf)
# convert PIL image object to Tkinter PhotoImage object
  tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)

#lastly, put the image into label
  label['image'] = tk_image


# create label widget and button widgets.
label =Label(root, bg='black') 
label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
button=Button(root, text = 'Press me', command = button)
button.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

#run 
root.mainloop()
```

I know for a fact the image URL works. Currently, it just shows the label as a 400x400 black square without an image on the button press.

excuse the terrible coding. :)
thanks

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation to the same as your original code?

Comment: oop, my bad. fixed it

Comment: Try `global tk_image` at the start of the function?

Comment: that worked. :) Thanks heaps